# Snake. Roll back the coordinates of the snake to impact

Tags: c#, wpf

I can’t realize the possibility of continuing the game after a collision. The snake should stop and start moving after clicking on one of the arrow buttons.

In a collision, a window appears about the loss, I need to continue the game.

[image: this]

I press the button and the following happens:

[image: this]

I don’t understand how I can save the coordinates of the snake just **before the collision**.
In the moveTimer_Tick method, all elements move, i.e. **new** coordinates have already appeared at the head and body, then there is a check for collisions with the wall and body. If they are found, a window appears about the loss.
New snake coordinates are not displayed. But after clicking the "Continue" button, an update occurs and the snake climbs to the border.

The question is: how can I save the coordinates of the snake, before the collision, and after continuing to start with them.

```
namespace Snake{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
          //The field on which the snake lives
          Entity field;
          // snake head
          Head head;
          // whole snake
          List<PositionedEntity> snake;
          // apple
          Apple apple;
          //number of points
          int score;
          // Is movement paused
          bool paused;
          //time
          DispatcherTimer moveTimer;

       //constructor form
       public MainWindow()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           snake = new List<PositionedEntity>();
           //create field 600x600pixels
           field = new Entity(600, 600, "pack://application:,,,/Resources/snake.png");

           //create a timer that runs every 300 ms
           moveTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
           moveTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 300);
           moveTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(moveTimer_Tick);

       }

       //redraw screen method
       private void UpdateField()
       {
           //update the position of the elements of the snake
           foreach (var p in snake)
           {
               Canvas.SetTop(p.image, p.y);
               Canvas.SetLeft(p.image, p.x);
           }

           //update the position of apple
           Canvas.SetTop(apple.image, apple.y);
           Canvas.SetLeft(apple.image, apple.x);

           //points update
           lblScore.Content = String.Format("{0}000", score);
       }

       //timer tick handler. All movement takes place here.
       void moveTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           // Do not update if movement is paused
           if(paused) {
               return;
           }

           //in the reverse order we move all the elements of the snake
           foreach (var p in Enumerable.Reverse(snake))
           {
               p.move();
           }

           //we check that the head of the snake did not crash into the body
           foreach (var p in snake.Where(x => x != head))
           {
               if (p.x == head.x && p.y == head.y)
               {
                   //we lose
                   moveTimer.Stop();
                   GameOver.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                   btnRestart.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                   tbScore.Text = String.Format("SCORE: {0}000", score);
                   return;
               }
           }

           //check that the head of the snake did not go out of the field
           if (head.x < 40 || head.x >= 540 || head.y < 40 || head.y >= 540)
           {
               //we lose
               moveTimer.Stop();
               GameOver.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
               btnRestart.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
               tbScore.Text = String.Format("SCORE: {0}000", score);
               return;
           }

           //check that the head of the snake crashed into an apple
           if (head.x == apple.x && head.y == apple.y)
           {
               //increase the score
               score++;
               //move the apple to a new place
               apple.move();
               var part = new BodyPart(snake.Last());
               canvas1.Children.Add(part.image);
               snake.Add(part);
           }
           UpdateField();
       }

       private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
       {
           // Unpause movement when any key is pressed
           if(paused) {
                paused = false;
           }
           switch (e.Key)
           {
               case Key.Up:
                   head.direction = Head.Direction.UP;
                   break;
               case Key.Down:
                   head.direction = Head.Direction.DOWN;
                   break;
               case Key.Left:
                   head.direction = Head.Direction.LEFT;
                   break;
               case Key.Right:
                   head.direction = Head.Direction.RIGHT;
                   break;
           }
       }

       // "Start"
       private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           btnStart.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
           btnRestart.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
           tBNotEnoughPoints.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
           score = 0;
           snake.Clear();
           canvas1.Children.Clear();
           // "Game Over"
           GameOver.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

           canvas1.Children.Add(field.image);
           apple = new Apple(snake);
           canvas1.Children.Add(apple.image);
           head = new Head();
           snake.Add(head);
           canvas1.Children.Add(head.image);

           moveTimer.Start();
           UpdateField();

       }
       private void btnContinue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           if (score >= 2)
           {
               GameOver.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
               btnRestart.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
               score -= 2;
               // Pause movement
               paused = true;
               moveTimer.Start();
               UpdateField();
           }
           else
           {
               tBNotEnoughPoints.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
           }
       }

       public class Entity
       {
           protected int m_width;
           protected int m_height;

           Image m_image;
           public Entity(int w, int h, string image)
           {
               m_width = w;
               m_height = h;
               m_image = new Image();
               m_image.Source = (new ImageSourceConverter()).ConvertFromString(image) as ImageSource;
               m_image.Width = w;
               m_image.Height = h;

           }

           public Image image
           {
               get
               {
                   return m_image;
               }
           }
       }

       public class PositionedEntity : Entity
       {
           protected int m_x;
           protected int m_y;
           public PositionedEntity(int x, int y, int w, int h, string image)
               : base(w, h, image)
           {
               m_x = x;
               m_y = y;
           }

           public virtual void move() { }

           public int x
           {
               get
               {
                   return m_x;
               }
               set
               {
                   m_x = value;
               }
           }

           public int y
           {
               get
               {
                   return m_y;
               }
               set
               {
                   m_y = value;
               }
           }
       }

       public class Apple : PositionedEntity
       {
           List<PositionedEntity> m_snake;
           public Apple(List<PositionedEntity> s)
               : base(0, 0, 40, 40, "pack://application:,,,/Resources/fruit.png")
           {
               m_snake = s;
               move();
           }

           public override void move()
           {
               Random rand = new Random();
               do
               {
                   x = rand.Next(13) * 40 + 40 ;
                   y = rand.Next(13) * 40 + 40 ;
                   bool overlap = false;
                   foreach (var p in m_snake)
                   {
                       if (p.x == x && p.y == y)
                       {
                           overlap = true;
                           break;
                       }
                   }
                   if (!overlap)
                       break;
               } while (true);

           }
       }

       public class Head : PositionedEntity
       {
           public enum Direction
           {
               RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT, UP, NONE
           };

           Direction m_direction;

           public Direction direction {
               set
               {
                   m_direction = value;
                   RotateTransform rotateTransform = new RotateTransform(90 * (int)value);
                   image.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
               }
           }

           public Head()
               : base(280, 280, 40, 40, "pack://application:,,,/Resources/head.png")
           {
               image.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
               m_direction = Direction.NONE;
           }

           public override void move()
           {
               switch (m_direction)
               {
                   case Direction.DOWN:
                       y += 40;
                       break;
                   case Direction.UP:
                       y -= 40;
                       break;
                   case Direction.LEFT:
                       x -= 40;
                       break;
                   case Direction.RIGHT:
                       x += 40;
                       break;
               }
           }
       }

       public class BodyPart : PositionedEntity
       {
           PositionedEntity m_next;
           public BodyPart(PositionedEntity next)
               : base(next.x, next.y, 40, 40, "pack://application:,,,/Resources/body.png")
           {
               m_next = next;
           }

           public override void move()
           {
               x = m_next.x;
               y = m_next.y;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Tip : Don't move the whole snake. Remove the tail and places it where the head should go, and makes it the head. If you want to rollback, save the removed tail part, then you can do the reverse : remove the head and place it where the tail was, and makes it the tail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something to say about the design of your code, but if you don't care and you want a fast (and ugly) solution you can modify your PositionEntity in order to store old coordinates:

```
   public class PositionedEntity : Entity
   {
       protected int m_x;
       protected int m_y;
       protected int m_oldX;
       protected int m_oldY;

       public PositionedEntity(int x, int y, int w, int h, string image)
           : base(w, h, image)
       {
           m_x = x;
           m_y = y;
           m_oldX = x;
           m_oldY = y;
       }

       public virtual void move() { }
       public virtual void RestorePrevious() 
       {
           m_x = m_oldX;
           m_y = m_oldY;          
       }

       public int x
       {
           get
           {
               return m_x;
           }
           set
           {
               m_oldX = m_x;
               m_x = value;
           }
       }

       public int y
       {
           get
           {
               return m_y;
           }
           set
           {
               m_oldY = m_y;
               m_y = value;
           }
       }
   }
```

When you have a collision you should call the RestorePrevious() on the head and on all the rest of the snake

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Added everything you said for the Body Part.
And for the head I prescribed the following:                                                   snake[0].x = snake[1].x;
snake[0].y = snake[1].y;
Everything works.